# How do I write to a text file in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab

I need to remove 'index.html' string from every line of my index.html files....

I need this to be done in MATLAB.

Here is what I have so far...

I don't know how to write the line, after I've modified it, back over the same line in the html file.

```
fid=fopen('index.html');

while ~feof(fid)

    tline=fgetl(fid);

if ~isempty(strfind(tline,'index.html'))
    remline=strrep( tline ,'index.html','');

**% fprintf(fid,remline);
%  fprintf('\n')**

end

end
```

### Update

This solution worked for me:

```
function WriteToFile(filename)



fid = fopen(filename, 'r+');
fid2 = fopen('index.txt', 'w');


while ~feof(fid)

    tline=fgetl(fid);

    if ~isempty(strfind(tline,'index.html'))
        remline=strrep(tline,'index.html','');

        fprintf(fid2, '%s\r\n', remline);
    else
        fprintf(fid2, '%s\r\n', tline);
    end
end

fclose(fid);
fclose(fid2);

delete(filename)
keyboard
movefile('index.txt','index.html')
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example function:

```
function WriteToFile(filename, text)
%open file with write permission
fid = fopen(filename, 'w');
%write a line of text
fprintf(fid, '%d\n', text);
%close file
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Replace %d with %s for actual text

Answer (score 3):

Replace %d with %s for actual text

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with text files it would be useful to study the documentation for functions such as `fileread` and `textscan`.  There's nothing wrong with the approach you are taking (well, apart from the obvious thing that you haven't got it working yet) but it's a bit more laborious than it needs to be.

I expect that if you read the file into a Matlab string (space limits permitting) then run a regex over it you can probably make your replacements in a oner.

Comment: I tried doing that. The problem is that fprintf truncated the string at the first occurrence of % - in the CSS parts.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `fopen()` opens the file for reading only, which is why the `fprintf()` call fails. However, this approach isn't going to work as it stands, because you are changing the length of the text lines.
I suggest you read each line from the input file, make your changes to it, then write it out to a temporary output file. When you have processed every input line, close both files, delete the input file, and rename the temporary output file to the original input file name.

Alternatively, as HPM suggests, read the whole file into memory in one go, process each line, and write it all out in one go 'on top of' the input input file.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying Niko's answer (replacing %d with %s) to put **actual text** into the file a1.m:

```
fid = fopen('a1.m','w');%open file for writing
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', 'some_text');%write a line of text
fclose(fid);%close file
```