# MATLAB: pretty function and writing to file

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save contents of MATLAB’s command windows to in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833356/how-to-save-contents-of-matlabs-command-windows-to-in-a-file)

Using function `pretty(x)` I get what I want in command window. I need to get the same in text file. How to do this?

Comment: Look for [how do I write text files in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598132/how-do-i-write-to-a-text-file-in-matlab). This question has been asked many times before.

Comment: I guess the main problem is not writing to text file, but to store the output of `pretty` in a string. If so, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833356/how-to-save-contents-of-matlabs-command-windows-to-in-a-file

Comment: Ways to do this are covered in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5833389/52738) to the question @H.Muster linked to, so this is basically a duplicate. I also added another option to my answer that uses EVALC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command evalc to redirect all output that would go to the console to a string variable (which you later can save to a file).

E.g.:

```
>> a = sym('a'); b = sym('b');
>> str = evalc('pretty(a+b)');
>> str 

str =


  a + b
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way is to use the clc disp() and char() commands:

```
clc % clear the command window
syms x y;
expression = x*y; % make your calculations
expression2 = x+y;% make your calculations
                  % make your calculations
disp(char(expression)) % char() converts symbolic expression to string
disp(char(expression2))% and disp() shows the string in the command window
```

You can copy everything in the command window really fast with the normal windows commands <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (select all), <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> (copy) and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> (paste).

Hope this helps